# Get all data variations from same sql table based on multiple periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

Table **TDatos** - contains ending and starting dates of each month
**appointment** - contains Valid From and Valid To dates

There is no any relation between the two tables, however, I want to select all **appointment.[Valid From]** date day differences with each month **DatosT.[Month Start]**

For example if appointment. **[Valid From]** is '2022-05-01' a selected data should look something like 120, 89, 61, 30, 0, -31 ... (for all 12 months of the year or more...)

I have done that using loop, but is there a way to do that without looping ?

```
/* declarations ... */ 

SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 12)
BEGIN
    set @month_start = (select top 1 month_start_date from TDatos where MonthNumber = @Counter)
    
    insert into @AllRecords
    select 
    DATEADD(day, [@month_start, Valid From]) as NewDays
    from appointment
END
```

Comment: *is there a way to do that without looping* - Yes, use a tally table.  See [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A `JOIN`, would likely (read will) be faster, but without *consumable* sample data and expected results, I wouldn't like to guess a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a recursive query or a RVC...

```
WITH 
T AS (select top 1 month_start_date, 1 AS N from TDatos where MonthNumber = 1
      UNION ALL 
      select top 1 month_start_date, N + 1 from TDatos where MonthNumber = N + 1)
    insert into @AllRecords
    select DATEADD(day, month_start, [Valid From])
    from appointment CROSS JOIN T;
```